# How can I have a multi-column dropdown box in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to create a multi-column combobox in c# wpf like below. Any Ideas?

[image]

When one row is selected, only the State code show up, but all detail could show up in the drop down selection.

Comment: Is it necessary to have two columns like that, since you won't be selecting individual elements anyway? You could just format the data to display both short code and state name?

Comment: I'm just curious, because the UI design doesn't allow that long string, sometimes it could only show like "CA - Ca" like that, and looks wired....

Comment: Do you mean your specific UI design doesn't allow you the width needed? Because you can make a combo box as wide as you want.

Comment: Yes, it's the UI Design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a little creative and solve this problem. Say you have a combo box that's only 60px wide. So you want combo items to be displayed as the full state name and abbreviation, like `CA - California`, but if selected, you only want the abbr. `CA`.

I declare a class to represent a state like so:

```
public class State
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    private string _displayName;
    public string DisplayName
    {
        set
        {
            _displayName = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_displayName))
                return string.Format("{0} - {1}", ShortName, FullName);
            else
                return _displayName;
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is that you use `DisplayName` to display items on the combo box. Then, in the `get` of `DisplayName`, if it already has a value, you return it, if not, you concatenate the short and full names of states.

Then when you do data binding, you have a list of states as well as a `SelectedState`, and in the setter of that property, you set the `DisplayName` to `ShortName`.

So, my `XAML`:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding States}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedState}"
              DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
              Name="CmbStates" Width="60" Height="32"/>
</Grid>
```

Then, in my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private List<State> _states;
    public List<State> States
    {
        get { return _states; }
        set
        {
            _states = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("States");
        }
    }

    private State _selectedState;
    public State SelectedState
    {
        get { return _selectedState; }
        set
        {
            _selectedState = value;
            SelectedState.DisplayName = SelectedState.ShortName;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedState");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        States = new List<State>
        {
            new State() { FullName = "California", ShortName = "CA" },
            new State() { FullName = "New York", ShortName = "NY" },
            new State() { FullName = "Oregon", ShortName = "OR" }
        };
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Now you should have the full concatenated name in the list:

[image]

But only the abbreviation when selected:

[image]